# SAS - using proc imported CSV in proc SQL (error)

Tags: sql, csv, sas, connection

I am looking to connect a CSV dataset I imported through 'proc import' with a dataset I am pulling from proc sql. Is there a way to toss my proc import file into proc sql? or vice versa?

here is where I'm at:

```
proc import datafile = 'filepath'
out = dataname
dbms = CSV
replace
;
run;

proc sql
connect to netezza as dbcon
(server="url" database=sandbox user=me password="&password.");

create table work as

select distinct * from connection to dbcon
(
select distinct a.*

from
dataname as a
left join
sqltable as b
on
a.number = b.number

);
quit;
```

I am currently receiving this error message but I am unsure where my syntax is wrong:

```
ERROR: CLI prepare error: ERROR:  relation does not exist database.ADMIN.dataname
SQL statement: select distinct a.*, b.* from dataname as a left join sqltable as b on a.number and b.number.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you connect to Netezza using the `CONNECT TO` statement, anything you have inside brackets such as:

```
select ... from connection to dbcon (...);
exec (...) by dbcon;
```

Is *inside* the Netezza box. The dataset you created called `dataname` is present in the work library where your SAS Session is running.

So the question can be solved in a few ways:

- Upload data to Netezza
- Use the libname Netezza engine to connect
- Create the table in Netezza using `Insert into` in SAS

#### Libname engine

You can usually translate a `connect to` statement into a libname statement as follows:

```
libname dbcon netezza server="url" database=sandbox user=me password="&password.";
```

If you create `dataname` in the dbcon library then your second query should work, provided you have permissions to create tables in the `sandbox` database.

Comment: Thank you, this worked well. It was easier to just set this into a libname statement and declare dbcon.sqltable in the proc sql statement. Thanks!